# Extra dot after U.S. or not?

Tags: grammar

> The country that will end up destroying itself is the U.S..

> The country that will end up destroying itself is the U.S.

Does it take an extra dot at the end or not?

Comment: Just one period. However, you can avoid it altogether by using: The U.S. is the country etc.

Comment: I'd avoid it altogether in a different way - by writing "the US" without dots. Dotless abbreviations seem to have been the norm in the UK for many decades, while Americans perhaps prefer to retain the dots. But regardless, you never end a sentence with a double dot. You can end with three or four dots if it's an ellipsis, but never two dots.

Answer (score 1):

No. An abbreviation has dots at the end, but having two dots would look awkward! Then, the second dot serves as the period.

It's like having a name at the beginning of a sentence: *Sam runs.* The capital S is both referring to the proper noun and the start of the sentence.

But you can still re-write it as *The U.S. is the country that will end up destroying itself.*

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. But I puzzled over your reference to **the second dot**, which I misread as meaning the second dot after the **S**.  May I suggest that you edit it slightly to avoid this confusion - possibly **the dot after the S serves as the period**.

Comment: @RonaldSoe go ahead!